# Syntax error versus compiler error in Visual Studio, or red wavy underline versus blue wavy underline

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, syntax-error

What is the difference between a "syntax error" and a "compiler error" as Visual Studio sees it?  Or, put another way, why are some "compile-time" errors underlined with *red* wavy lines and some with *blue* wavy lines?  Here is an example:

[image]

The red underlined error above has this description:

> No overload for method 'ValidateFilteredRecipient' takes 6 arguments

The blue underlined error has this description:

> 'ValidateBuild': cannot declare instance members in a static class

It's not clear to me what the distinguishing characteristics of the two errors are.

I thought finding the answer would be a piece of cake: I'd just google it and the first result would be an MSDN page expounding this topic fully; however, very surprisingly, this was not the case.  I started off by trying to google the colors (since I didn't yet know red meant "syntax error" and blue meant "compiler error"):

[visual studio red underline vs. blue underline](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=visual+studio+red+underline+vs.+blue+underline)

No help there.  Then I tried these searches:

[visual studio error underline color meanings](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=visual+studio+error+underline+color+meanings)
[visual studio underline color meanings](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=visual+studio+underline+color+meanings)

I could see that this was going nowhere, so I googled a bit more and figured out where the colors were set in VS: **Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors**.  By the way, the inability to search the huge list here is extremely annoying, but I figured out that "syntax errors" have the red wavy underline, and "compiler errors" have the blue wavy underline.

[image]

So what do those mean?  Back to Google:

[visual studio compiler error vs. syntax error](https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=visual+studio+compiler+error+vs.+syntax+error)

Nothing relevant.  Here's the closest I've found, from MSDN:

[Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw7t0545.aspx)

This page has these entries:

> Compiler Error -- Blue squiggles in the editor indicating a compiler error.

and

> Syntax Error -- Parse errors.

Not at all helpful -- emphasis on "at all".  I have always thought I knew what a "syntax error" was, at least, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error) agrees:

> a syntax error is an error in the syntax of a sequence of characters
>   or tokens that is intended to be written in a particular programming
>   language.

Also, [here is what what it has for syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)):

> the syntax of a computer language is the set of rules that defines the
>   combinations of symbols that are considered to be a correctly
>   structured document or fragment in that language.

So, going back to my "syntax error" from above:

> No overload for method 'ValidateFilteredRecipient' takes 6 arguments

How is that a syntax error per the definition I've included here?  Actually, in my opinion, the "compiler error" I got more-closely meets this definition of a syntax error:

> 'ValidateBuild': cannot declare instance members in a static class

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre -- "something that you can't do or the compiler won't allow you to" <--- a.k.a. "something you have done wrong".

Comment: Reluctant upvote for a question that's very well put together, but also a bit of a shaggy dog story when I realized exactly what it is you're studying in depth. Red wavy lines, blue wavy lines, can't we all just get along?

Comment: @JeroenMostert -- I totally understand.  But doesn't it bug you??  I mean, this is a commercial, enterprise-level IDE....For the sake of solving a puzzle, at least...why are they not just one error type?  And why aren't they documented?

Comment: Not very technical I realize, but in my experience with the IDE I've generally come to think of them as "red means this is known to be wrong right now" and "blue means this was wrong the last time we tried to compile but we don't currently know for certain".  I can't think of an actual practical moment when the difference really mattered though, I've always just corrected and compiled and moved on.

Comment: @David -- Hence why it took me so long to finally ask this question.  I guess it just bugged me too many times, but I always did as you did and just fixed the error and moved on.

Comment: Does it bug me that a commercial, enterprise-level IDE has two distinct categorizations of error in its interface with an unclear delineation between the two? No, absolutely not. I'm also one of those people who turns on "warnings as errors", so as far as I'm concerned there's only one category: "error". If this truly bugged me, I'd simply change both colors to red!

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre -- I disagree with the last part of your statement.  Everything with my overload call is valid syntax as I have interpreted the definition (which I referenced in my question).  It's not like I used an illegal character or an incorrect ordering of keywords.  I just left out a method param.

Comment: Oh man would I love to know why I got a down vote.  Seriously?  If it's a "not useful" thing, then why would MS have ever bothered to differentiate the colors?  Obviously MS thought it was useful to do so.

Comment: this is a good question.  I enjoyed the that you added actual links to your google searches.

Comment: Interesting that in my case I see red underlines for both types of errors. I actually don't remember when I saw blue underline last time :) Maybe because of Resharper...

Comment: Yup kudos for calling this out - definitely made me think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference between the syntax error and compilation error is when Visual Studio detects it.

Syntax error is detected and highlighted as you code. You do not have to build the code to get these errors.

However, Compilation errors are complex that Editor cannot detect as you code. You will have to run it through a compiler (do a build) to identify them. So the chances are one might end up continue coding without compiling and will not be able to detect them until he builds.

Basically, Syntax errors are a subset of compilation errors. If you use text editor like notepad to write your code, you will never see syntax error. All will be logged as Compilation errors when you run the code through compiler.

In regards to highlighting them differently, I think it is a visual representation for the Developer to understand what he could have caught this while writing the code.

As mentioned by everyone, at the end of day, you need to fix both to make you code run.

This is true for any programming language and the editor used along with that language.

Answer (score 4):

Both Syntax and compiler errors will prevent your code from compiling.

Syntax Errors refer to how your code interacts with other pieces of code. Things like type mismatches when passing parameters to functions etc.

Compiler errors on the other hand refer to more fundamental architectural violations like trying to inherit from sealed classes or defining non static members inside static classes. These go against the definition of the language rather than the usage of the language.

Comment: "These go against the **definition of the language**" -- Isn't that the language's syntax?

Comment: I think there needs to be a distinction between these two types of errors - whether you call it a syntax error or something else is semantics. IMO A syntax error is merely a different category of compiler error.

Comment: I agree with you there, definitely.  I'm just flummoxed at how MS bothered to differentiate the two in the first place and then dropped the ball on the implementation.

Comment: BTW: I see your point: all code you write needs to adhere to the syntax of the language or it wont compile. I believe the distinction that is being made is between definition syntax (declaring classes and methods - results in compiler errors) vs. implementation syntax (the stuff inside the methods - results in syntax errors)

Comment: Generating a good error message for a syntax error is pretty tricky.  The parser simply does not understand what you want to do and has to *guess* at what was intended.  "No overload for method" is not a terrible message, but it has no idea if *this* code is wrong or the method declaration was wrong.  A compiler error is much easier, it knows with 100% confidence what you did wrong.  Fwiw, the syntax error messages that the C# compiler generates are quite good, they paid a *lot* of attention to them.

Comment: @HansPassant - really? In rory's example, did they intend to make the class non-static or the member static?

Comment: Really.  Nobody accidentally declares a class *static*.

Comment: LOL! I agree declaration of a static class would not be accidental, however when converting a static class to a non-static implementation (it could happen if you are trying to convert to an IOC methodology and want to remove the dependancy on a static class) may result in one accidentally leaving the "static" declaration.